# Looking for a packet builder

Tags: networking, sniffing

Can anyone recommend a quality packet builder?  I'm analyzing network traffic (academic purposes) with Wireshark, and I'd like to be able to create packets as well.  Open Source is always a bonus.

I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: I'll be trying these out over the weekend and update when I've picked my favorite - thanks to all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. If you are willing to dabble a bit in **Python**,
   [**Scapy**](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) is a [good tool](http://sectools.org/packet-crafters.html).
2. For simpler activities, [**hping3**](http://wiki.hping.org/94) is a quick **Tcl** based tool.

An important advantage with these is, they are available as debian packages.

Answer (score 1):

I used to use [Packetyzer](http://www.paglo.com/opensource/packetyzer). But @nik's suggestion of Scapy is what I would have used had I needed to forge more than a few packets.

Answer (score 1):

There are various packet builders hardware and software based (see my listing below).

For your purposes I can only agree with [nik's](https://superuser.com/users/263/nik) [recommendation](https://superuser.com/a/104486/59605).

---

- **Software based packet generators**

  - Windows

    - [Packet Generator Tool](http://www.netscantools.com/nstpro_packet_generator.html) (prorietary)
  - Linux/Unix

    - [pierf](http://pierf.sourceforge.net/) (BSD)
    - [TCPivo](http://www.thefengs.com/wuchang/work/tcpivo/) (-)
    - [Network Expect](http://netexpect.org/wiki) (GPL)
    - [pktgen](ftp://robur.slu.se/pub/Linux/net-development/pktgen-testing/) (-)
  - Cross platform

    - [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) (GPLv2)
    - [Tcpreplay](http://tcpreplay.synfin.net/) (GPLv3) (Win, Unix/Linux)
    - [hping](http://www.hping.org/) (GPLv2) (MacOSX, Linux/Unix, Windows)
    - [Nemesis](http://nemesis.sourceforge.net/) (-) (MacOSX, Linux/Unix, Windows)
    - [Bit-Twist](http://bittwist.sourceforge.net/) (-) (MacOSX, Linux/Unix, Windows)
    - [AnetTest](http://anettest.sourceforge.net/) (-) (Linux/Unix, Windows)
    - [packETH](http://packeth.sourceforge.net/) (GPLv2) (Linux, MAC OS)
    - [enter link description here](http://www.perihel.at/sec/mz/) (GPLv2) (Linux, FreeBSD)

---

- **Hardware based packet generators**

  - [NetFPGA - Packet generator](http://netfpga.org/foswiki/bin/view/NetFPGA/OneGig/PacketGenerator)
  - [NuDog](http://www.omnicor.biz/nudog_-_small_ip_packet_generator_-_usb_power.aspx)
  - [PacketJet](http://netfpga.org/foswiki/bin/view/NetFPGA/OneGig/PacketGenerator)
  - [CT503 - Traffic Generator](http://www.candelatech.com/ct503_product.php)
  - [Xena ethernet traffic generator](http://www.phoenixdatacom.com/xena.html)
  - [SunSet XTT-5000](http://www.phoenixdatacom.com/sunrisextt5000.html)
  - [Packetstorm Network Emulator](http://www.phoenixdatacom.com/packetstorm.html)
  - [NuStreams-2000](http://www.omnicor.biz/ethernet_test_system_nustreams_2000_.aspx)
  - [Continuum](http://www.nextcomputing.com/products/industry-solutions/continuum)

Answer (score 0):

[Netwox](http://www.laurentconstantin.com/en/netw/netwox/) will likely do what you want.  It did a lot of that stuff for me (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121458/how-can-i-simulate-tcp-ip-errors)).

Answer (score 0):

What is your OS?I am testing network monitor under windows, and I am using [Colasoft Packet Builder](http://www.colasoft.com/download/products/download_packet_builder.php).